# Intellij IDEA rebuilds entire module each time jUnit test is run

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a large project with several modules including one large "src" module, and each compilation takes at least 5-10 minutes. I'm unable to refactor the structure of the project to potentially speed up compilation.

Every time I try to run a JUnit test, IntelliJ always compiles the entire module before running the tests (even if no files changed).

Other answers suggested using the Eclipse compiler and the "Make, no error check" launch command instead of the regular "Make". I tried that but IntelliJ is still rebuilding the entire module.

**Edit**: This seems to be related to how errors and handled with "Make, No Error Check". My project contains errors in unrelated areas of the code (managed by other teams) that I was using the eclipse compiler to skip over. After "fixing" those errors, incremental compilation works again. Maybe the build is considered invalid (and is discarded) even if errors are skipped?

Comment: Invalidate caches, report a bug - it should work fine out of the box.

Comment: More info about the project is needed, but it is 100% bug and this may be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135483

Answer (score 1):

Change your run configuration to not make the module:

Go to `Run -> Edit Configurations` (or click the `Edit Configurations` from the Run dropdown menu), and you'll see this screen:
[image: Run Configs]
Remove "Make" from `Before launch`, and it should work

P.S. I would suggest renaming it to something like: `JUnit tests (NO REBUILD)` otherwise you might be in for some serious head-scratching later on :)

Comment: Without a make, I was getting errors for missing classes for every class used in my test. I think compilation errors were preventing my build from being cached even with "Make, No Error Check".

Comment: Bug tracker is right there -> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA